# Find frame number in H264 stream

Tags: h.264

I am writing a parser for a H264 stream (that is illegaly put to an avi file). I made some progress and I also can parse the frames itself to decode them (using VideoToolbox from Apple). That works so far.

The problem now is: I would like to seek to a specific frame in the video stream. I read the avi index and now I have access to all IDR frames. Unfortunately, every IDR frame has `frame_num` = 0, what is correct after the specification.

How can I figure out, what frame number the NALU has in the whole video?